What is the "Rule of 80" in Connection with Israel?
I am not a Muslim.  In discussions about Israel/Palestine with Muslims online, a number of them have referenced a "rule of 80" in connection with Israel.  From the context of the discussions, it seemed to be that they were saying that Israel would last only 80 years.
Does anyone know the source of this "rule of 80"? Is there any authority for interpreting this source as applying to the modern state of Israel?

It is about Psalm 90 verse 10:

Our days may come to seventy years,
or eighty, if our strength endures; yet the best of them are but trouble and sorrow,
for they quickly pass, and we fly away.

Applying that to a state or nation might have a little bit of over-interpretation.

What is the basis for applying it Israel?

@conceptualinertia for any reason of applying that to the state of Israel or the nation, you have to ask those who promote this. One thing I can think of is that they hope for the fall of Israel and try to bent anything they find into this direction.
